# Finding orthologs

Tags: orthologues

I am interested in finding an ortholog for a particular gene in fungi.

Comment: Hi what are you goals for the research?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and give us more context. What species is your original gene in? What fungi are you looking at? Are they close to your starting species? Far? What kind of orthology are you looking for? Do you require functional equivalence? Does your gene code for a protein and does this protein have any functional domains? You almost certainly want to start with blasting your protein against a _translated_ genome (tBLASTn) but the details will depend on what you're after exactly.